# Hazelcast ClassNotFoundException for replicated maps

Tags: hazelcast

I have an issue with hazelcast v 3.6.2.
Here is and replicatedmap config in hazelcast.xml for

```
<replicatedmap name="default">
<in-memory-format>BINARY</in-memory-format>
</replicatedmap>
```

Here is a slice of code which rises an classnotfound exception:

```
    ReplicatedMap<Object, Object> r1 = getHazelCastInstance().getReplicatedMap("DDD");
    TokenDef tf = new TokenDef();
    tf.setLanguage("en");
    tf.setTokenId("RRRR");
    tf.setSiebelPassword("RRR");
    r1.put("eeee",tf);
    r1.remove("eeee"); //!!! CLASS NOT FOUND EXCEPTION
```

Very strange that it puts token without an exception, but raises on the remove string.
It works if I use simple IMap instead of replicated map. Could anyone explain where is difference ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please add the stacktrace?

Comment: com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: Problem while reading DataSerializable, namespace: 0, id: 0, class: 'lv.ipr.siebel.model.TokenDef', exception: lv.ipr.siebel.model.TokenDef
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializer.read(DataSerializer.java:130)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializer.read(DataSerializer.java:47)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:46)
        at

Comment: It is on HZ node part.

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23163154/exc.txt

Comment: Did you deploy the classes on the nodes?

Comment: No, i set a node as a binary memory format. And it works for getMap() fine. For getReplicatedMap only put object works first time. When I update and remove object it raises CNF exception.

Comment: Yeah we already opened an issue for that. You're right if the member is set to binary there shouldn't be any deserialization. You can follow the issue here: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/8014

Comment: OK thanks :) I will use IMap then.